# How to define the function in curve fitting?

Tags: python, curve-fitting

Okay so I am trying to do curve fitting and when I look at the documentations I see they use functions for it. In scipy it is this

```
 def func(x, a, b, c):
     return a * np.exp(-b * x) + c
```

and in another website it is something like this

```
 def func(x, a, b):
     return a * np.sin(b * x)
```

I am facing with some errors but before understanding them I need to get how do we know which function to use ? Am I missing a big point here ? How do we define the function we are going to use ?

Comment: you should have some idea about the data you want to fit a function to.

Comment: This is rather a question for another forum, i.e. have a look at the following answer: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/132652/how-to-determine-which-distribution-fits-my-data-best/132700#132700 This is not a programming problem, rather a statistics question.

Comment: @Sosel your referenced link is for statistical distribution fitting, not curve fitting per this question.

Comment: I have an open source Python curve fitting web site zunzun.com that has a "function finder" which can suggest candidate equations for curve fitting. It will fit data to several hundred known, named equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can visualize the data that you have, you will have an idea of what function could be fitted to the data. If you cannot view the data, then I would suggest choosing a few different functions and observing the error between the fit and the data points.

Consider

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oFPJV.png)

fitted with a linear function and

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMObs.png)

fitted with a non-linear function.